# AttributeError and lost exception message

Tags: python

It seems Python handles `AttributeError` exception non-standard.
When a class defines `__getattr__` method, it swallows this exception instead of propagation further to top of the stack. Is the original exception lost ?

```
class A(object):
    @property
    def test(self):
        raise AttributeError('message which should not be lost')
        return 'this would never return'

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print 'Trying get attribute: ', name
        # how decide if AttributeError was already raised ??
        return 42

a = A()
print a.test
# Trying get attribute:  test
# 42
```

Imagine the `AttributeError` exception may arise anywhere at arbitrary depth in call chain.

The question is how preserve the original exception instance with `'message which should not be lost'` message ? Is there some way how keep the AttributeError without recourse to workarounds like replacing with different exception class ?

Comment: Don't mix properties, and `__getattr__` then. `__getattr__` is called whenever `__getattribute__` encounters an `AttributeError`. Yes, the exception may well be lost.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Unfortunately sometimes it can't be avoided. For example I'm working with Django based shop application and it introduces `__getattr__` in Form subclass. At form's validation all attribute exceptions are silenced and it drives me nut discover from where errors come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving the [`object.__getattribute__()` handler](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) a signal that the attribute doesn't exist by raising an `AttributeError`. The defined behaviour is to then call `__getattr__` instead. The exception is lost, it was handled by `__getattribute__`. From the documentation:

> Called unconditionally to implement attribute accesses for instances of the class. If the class also defines `__getattr__()`, the latter will not be called unless `__getattribute__()` either calls it explicitly or raises an `AttributeError`.

If you don't want `__getattribute__` to handle the exception, you need to move your `__getattr__` behaviour over to a custom `__getattribute__` method instead:

```
class A(object):
    @property
    def test(self):
        raise AttributeError('message which should not be lost')
        return 'this would never return'

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            value = super(A, self).__getattribute__(name)
        except AttributeError as ae:
            # chance to handle the attribute differently
            # if not, re-raise the exception
            raise ae
```

Note that the [`hasattr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) behaves the same way; it'll return `False` when an exception is raised when trying to access the attribute.

Comment: Thanks. To make it clear, if class defines `__getattr__`, there is no other way then reraise `AttributeError` in it to propagate the exception, regardless if `__getattribute__` is defined. If need save the exception instance, need do it in `__getattribute__` ?

Comment: @JoanBlackmoore: you'd have to completely re-implement `__getattribute__` (so not call the `super()` version) to avoid it swallowing the exception, *or* you need to rename the `__getattr__` method and then call that renamed version from the `__getattribute__` override I've shown.

Comment: Thanks again, sounds a bit hackish though. Btw. calling `hasattr` anywhere in getattr methods seems to lead to infinite recursion. You've probably meant use it at place of attribute access, but this is almost impossible to do when working with 3rd party code.

Comment: @JoanBlackmoore: yes, `hasattr()` triggers `__getattribute__` which can trigger `__getattr__` if the attribute doesn't exist. Attribute access and `__getattr__` can get very convoluted and lead to strange hard to diagnose issues, see http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201010/surprising_getattr_recursion.html for example.

Comment: Would you find some downside when exception instance would be assigned to class instance variable (or cleared if not raised) in `__getattribute__` and then test it in `__getattr__` ?

Comment: @JoanBlackmoore: the problem is that the `object.__getattribute__` implementation you will need to call to implement things like descriptor handling (a `property` is a descriptor, as are functions) calls `__getattr__`; you cannot intercept the swallowing of the `AttributeError` when `__getattr__` is present.